# Want to finsh my basement

Tags: basement, framing, finish

I am looking to finish my basement,how do i calculate for the needed materials such as sheet rock and the studs for framing?

Comment: You're also going to have to consider emergency escape and rescue openings, if they're not already built into the home.

Answer (score 1):

- How high are the walls. Feet or Meters ?? You did not specify where on Earth you are located.
- How Wide is each wall.

Normal Sheet Rock 4' High X 8' Wide 
So you take Ceiling Height (probably 8' ) Divide by my sheet rock height 4' = 2.

Basement room Walls W1 + W2 + W3 + W4 = W_total Width 
Divide W_total Width by 8 the Sheet Rock Width = Total_For_4'_High_Wall.
Total_For_4'_High_Wall * 2 because we want the wall to be all the way to the ceiling. This is equal to total sheet rock required for the Basement.

Studs 16 Inch on Center Divide W_total Width by 16. Since you mentioned Framing - you have a base framing and top framing you will also need to add W_total Width multiply by two and divide by your base and top frame board lengths say 8' for ease but you can buy 10 or 12 foot boards as well.

**EDITED 5-10-2016** to provide an example with the OPS Dimensions.

[image: Example With your provided dimensions]

Comment: If you have 12' wide walls, you could use two 4x12 sheets, rather than four 8' sheets. But I guess in a basement, you might have trouble getting 12' sheets down there.

Comment: Hey Thanks Ken, I am in Northan  Virginia , my basement is divided in three sections, The largest area is 12'W x 30'L x 10'H . the other area is along the length of the larger which has me to assume the are equally divided,which has a petition in the middle. Did not measure, wanted to wait to get answer. Thanks

Comment: @E-Gene I used your dimensions and drew a quick sketch. You should start using full boards from the top and work down when you are at the bottom use your split boards (12' x 2 or 8' x 2') - your baseboard will cover up for minor variances in measurement and imperfect cuts. N.Va I grew up there.